# Would calling methods with the the parameters on new lines be considered bad practice?

Tags: php

I'm curious as to what the best practice for passing multiple parameters to a method is. Specifically, I'm wondering wether or not calling methods with comments and parameters on new lines would be considered bad practice or not.

```
// get json from database
$json = $this->mysql->get_json_from_entries($this->table,   // data table
                                            $foo,           // column
                                            $bar,           // column value
                                            $this->limit);  // maximum rows to retrieve
```

as opposed to

```
// get json from database
$json = $this->mysql->get_json_from_entries($this->table, $foo, $bar, $this->limit);
```

Comment: I don't think it is a bad practice but you definitely should document your interface, not parameters

Comment: Barring any restrictions in language syntax for parsing, I'd say the general rule of thumb is "do what makes sense and makes it easily readable/understandable."  Hard-and-fast code formatting rules should always give way to best judgement in any particular case.

Comment: Coding style discussions are never going to be anything but an invitation to outright religious warfare.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I feel like it might be kind of unnecessary (bulky) since I'm keeping my interface well documented. On the other hand, if I were reading my code for the first time, I think the first one would make way more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a matter of taste but normally from what I have seen its all on one line and then you use your DOC blocks like so:

```
/**
  *  Get json from database
  *
  * @param $this->table object data table
  * @param $foo string column name
  * ...etc
  */
$json = $this->mysql->get_json_from_entries($this->table, $foo, $bar, $this->limit);
```

Comment: I think this is the better style, especially for the OP's example function which only accepts 4 arguments. Maybe for functions that accept more arguments, breaking it into lines would be a better idea (although I still wouldn't make one line per variable). If you are using the OP's style for all of your method calls, you can have one messy looking PHP file.

Comment: My interface is using DOC blocks, so maybe this would be more appropriate? Either way, thanks for your input.

Comment: Wouldn't the docblock go above the function definition?

Comment: @Adam Yes, was just showing his example for ease but +1 for the call out.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think really long lines are worse.

You might be interested in the [Zend Framework Coding Standard for PHP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.html) more generally.

Comment: +1 for referencing a consistent coding standard (even if Zend don't use it consistently)… I’d go with all on one line unless that makes the line longer than 80 characters. Specific section of Zend standard: [Function and method usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html#coding-standard.coding-style.functions-and-methods.usage).

Comment: @cbuckley Agreed, why some editors have a margin line set at about that width - good for printing too.

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to lean towards best practices, but sometimes (if the function has too many arguments) the first style is preferred by me as well.

2 things though:
If a function has too much parameters, you might consider refactoring it, maybe put the parameters in a new class or change the implementation of the class itself
Second, try to declare variables with verbose names, which describes its usage. Hint: php does NOT follow these practices :)